# Spring 3.2: Choose view basing on user role

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Using **spring-webmvc** and **spring-security-web** of version 3.2, I'd like to return different views  depending on the user role (or whether user is authenticated or not), so that for a `"/"` request a user of role *ANONYMOUS* (or not authenticated user) gets the *welcome* page and a user of role *USER* gets the *home* page.

My current approach is doing this with a regular controller:

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeCtrl {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome(Principal principal) {
        if (userAuthenticated(principal)) {
            return "redirect:home";
        }
        return "welcome";
    }

    private boolean userAuthenticated(Principal principal) {
        return principal != null && principal instanceof Authentication
                && hasUserRole((Authentication) principal);
    }

    private boolean hasUserRole(Authentication principal) {
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = (principal)
                .getAuthorities();
        return Iterables.contains(Collections2.transform(authorities,
                new Function<GrantedAuthority, String>() {

                    @Override
                    public String apply(GrantedAuthority authority) {
                        return authority.getAuthority();
                    }
                }), "ROLE_USER");
    }

}
```

However, I don't really like it because I feel that this redirection should be done with spring security (am I wrong?). Do you know any way of doing this with Spring Security configuration? My current config is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/welcome").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().formLogin()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home").permitAll()
                .and().logout().permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder)
            throws Exception {
        authManagerBuilder.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user")
                .password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me, this is the best way to use spring security configuration latest in the market.

General support for Java Configuration was added to Spring framework in Spring 3.1. Since Spring Security 3.2 there has been Spring Security Java Configuration support which enables users to easily configure Spring Security without the use of any XML.

If you are familiar with the Security Namespace Configuration then you should find quite a few similarities between it and the Security Java Configuration support and you can use Security Namespace Configuration as well which suites you

There are many new things added to the spring security 3.2 you can use that
like

1). Java Configuration -- better for those who are more familiar to read the jar files to apply the configuration methods.

2). Concurrency Support -- In most environments, Security is stored on a per Thread basis. This means that when work is done on a new Thread, the SecurityContext is lost. Spring Security provides some infrastructure to help make this much easier for users. Spring Security provides low level abstractions for working with Spring Security in multi threaded environments. In fact, this is what Spring Security builds on to integration with AsyncContext.start(Runnable) and Spring MVC Async Integration.

3). CSRF Attacks :- Assume that your bank’s website provides a form that allows transferring money from the currently logged in user to another bank account. For example, the HTTP request might look like:

```
POST /transfer HTTP/1.1
Host: bank.example.com
Cookie: JSESSIONID=randomid; Domain=bank.abc.com; Secure; HttpOnly
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

amount=100.00&routingNumber=1234&account=9876
```

Now pretend you authenticate to your bank’s website and then, without logging out, visit an evil website. The evil website contains an HTML page with the following form:

```
<form action="https://bank.example.com/transfer" method="post">
  <input type="hidden"
      name="amount"
      value="100.00"/>
  <input type="hidden"
      name="account"
      value="evilsAccountNumber"/>
  <input type="submit"
      value="ohh you Win Money!"/>
</form>
```

You like to win money, so you click on the submit button. In the process, you have unintentionally transferred $100 to a malicious user. This happens because, while the evil website cannot see your cookies, the cookies associated with your bank are still sent along with the request.

such type of the attacks can easily be stopped by using the spring security 3.2, as this new feature **Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Protection** in spring security generate some token which are matched at the payment gateway side.

and many more advantages......................

Comment: @Macias have you satisfied with my answer, is it looks good to you my friend

Comment: @Macias If it looks good to you, please upvote it so it will be helpful for others my friend

Comment: So where exactly in this copy-paste from spring documentation is an answer to my question? -1 for that my friend